# Experiments for a model particle accelerator

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I'd appreciate everyone's ideas for interesting/educational physics experiments that can be performed with a model particle accelerator.  The model uses an Arduino micro-controller to pulse electromagnets which accelerate a steel ball around a tube.  The experiments should be suitable for advanced senior high school through to undergraduate.  The model looks like this:
[image: Desktop model particle accelerator]

Existing experiment ideas (to be formally defined in due course) are:

Easy
- How does ball speed vary with voltage applied to the electromagnet?
- Quantify the friction between ball and tube surface by investigating the ball speed when rolling to a stop.

Intermediate
- How does the ball speed vary with electromagnetic pulse duration and timing ?
- How much residual magnetism exists in the ball as it travels between electromagnets ?
- What is the optical angle of internal reflection for the strobes to light up the tube ?

Advanced
- How does the speed and repeatability of the ball speed measurements vary with ball size ?
- Set up the particle accelerator as a pendulum clock - what changes are needed ?
- Use your previous friction measurement to predict roll/slip dynamics and confirm experimentally.

Very advanced
- Will the unit operate if tipped vertically ? If so, can it be used to estimate the value of gravity ? Research gravity variations across Earth's surface and develop an experiment and plan for model accelerator enthusiasts globally to submit their experimental data and map gravity variations.
- Typically a permanent magnet near the tube would cause drag on the ball and reduce rotational speed, however there is one place a permanent magnet can be situated which increases rotational speed... answer from theory and demonstrate experimentally

Experiments involving vacuum pressure and shooting the ball out of the tube are under development, but for now, please focus on the existing hardware as shown above.

What are your ideas for experiments ?

For more details/videos on the model, please see https://hackaday.io/project/167065-working-model-particle-accelerator/details

Thanks
Dan